# How to send an app to background in WP8

Tags: c#, javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an wp8 app with Apache Cordova, I want override the backbutton of the app and trigger the menu button event. To be more in context: Is a music player app, if I'm playing music and I press the home button, then theres no problem. The music keeps playing in background, everything is fine. But if I press the back button and I exit the app, then the app dies. Thats why I want to override the back button behaviour.
I tried to find a plugin that allow me this, like [this](https://github.com/mohamed-salah/phonegap-backbutton-plugin) one, that I'm using in the android version. But I didn't find anything. Then I tried to search in the `PhoneApplicationPage` [api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage(v=vs.105).aspx) page. But I didn't find anything. I really need some type of workaround. Any feedback is usefull.

Comment: Are you sure you want to override the behavior of the back button? It is commonly known as exiting (and killing) an app. How would a user exit your app in your scenario?

Comment: @venerik The user will exit the app with a logout button that is in the menu. Soundcloud and spotify does as well. I don't know if they use a service in background or something like that.